# Problema al conectar SqlServer con Spring boot

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot

Hola tengo un problema al conectar spring boot con SqlServer. al ejecutar el programa me sale este error.

```
Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Este es mi archivo properties:

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=lineaSobreRuedasExpresoBanos;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 1234
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# JPA specific configs
spring.jpa.database-platform =  org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.show_sql =   true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Ya he intendado de todo y no se conecta

este es el Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.SobreRuedas</groupId>
    <artifactId>SobreRuedas2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SobreRuedas2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

esa es la cabecera del pom y aqui estan las dependencias que tengo

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ahi estan las dependencias con todo el archivo Pom, y nc si me falta alguna otra dependencia o si es error de otra cosa, estoy usando Spring Boot 2.0.4 en eclipse y usando Sql Server 2012.

Comment: Cómo tienes el POM?

Comment: ya lo actualice ahi estan todas las depencias y todo lo que tengo en el POM

Comment: Quita el scope test de la dependencia del driver y asegúrate de especificar la versión

Comment: Si lo hice pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: Asegúrate entonces que maven te esté descargando el jar del driver y que esté cargado en tu IDE.

Comment: Si esta!! lo descarga y lo coloca en mi proyecto pero no lo encuentra.

Comment: Acabo de probar con tus claves de configuración y con la dependencia del POM (con el scope por defecto en vez de tetst) y tengo este error: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Por tal motivo pienso que estás teniendo un problema con tu IDE. Te recomiendo que pruebas ejecutando el proyecto desde la terminal a ver si te ocurre los mismo: mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: me sale el mismo errror que no encuentra la clase SQLServerDriver

Comment: ¿Pudieras probar con una configuración para una base de datos tipo H2 a ver que tal? [Este artículo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) te puede ayudar. Los cambios son mínimos respecto a lo que tienes ahora.

Comment: Mira, me monté un servidor SQL Server 2017 Development Edition en mi docker y usando tu misma configuración me pude conectar sin problema alguno. Tu problema tiene que estar en que el JAR del driver no se está encontrando. Trata de probar con H2 como te dije a ver si ese driver si te lo descarga.

Comment: y como funciona ese driver?? porque necesito usar Sql Server si o si

Comment: Si claro, se que tienes que usar MSSQLServer. Eso es una base de datos que se crea en la memoria RAM automáticamente solo con hacer la configuración que te explica el artículo. Lo que intento es determinar si tienes un problema con tu configuración de Maven/IDE que te impida localizar tu driver al momento de ejecutar la aplicación. Eso solo para probar si de este modo levanta la aplicación.

Comment: Con otra base si se levanta, probe con MySql y PostgresSql, pero con SqlServer no funciona

Comment: Lo siento pero ya no se como ayudarte. Por último prueba con esta definición de la dependencia del driver a ver que tal:<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar</version>
</dependency>

Comment: la propiedad para el driver seria `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` verifica porque la propiedad  que utilizas ha cambiado para spring boot 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola en teoría debe de ser así. Saludos!

```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=dbtest
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=Pass@$#
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```